# What is the range on a fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

In particular, I want to know the range of the coefficients on the type-IV discrete cosine transform. Assuming no normalization factor or window is applied, what interval can I expect the coefficients to reside on?

I realize this is a fairly simple question, but unfortunately, Google has yielded no answers.

Comment: The range rather depends on the domain on which you consider the transform. What kind of signals do you put in? (Also: see [dsp.se] site)

Comment: The inputs normalized into the range [-1, 1].

Comment: Then you can estimate the coefficients by applying $|f \cos (\dots)|\le 1$ in the formula for the coefficients.